# git-upgrade ERR! Restore initial sources(react-native-git-upgrade)

Tags: ios, git, react-native, react-native-ios

I want to upgrade my React-native project version

but wen I use react-native-git-upgrade to upgrade,Is wrong

this is my code to upgrade in terminal

`react-native-git-upgrade 0.48.0`

But it was wrong，look this picture
[this is error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipSMD.png)

what should I do now?

It's run on XCode9 MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

current react-native version is 0.44

I want to upgrade to 0.48.0

Comment: Please embed the image in question.

Comment: please be more specific: what steps did you do? what were you expecting to happen? what's the error? what are you trying to achieve? which programs/OS and versions are you using?

Comment: sorry，I edit my question，Looking forward to your reply

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is only to have a new version of react native, then just update the version in the package.json and run "npm install" on the project folder.

Your problem is another one, and related mostly to how git works.

Comment: I used to use npm install, but there will be A lot of missing files, so I use react-native-git-upgrade.